# regarding the post processing of data files input using fread

Tags: r, data.table

I once saw the following code segment for reading and processing the csv file.

```
cd<-fread('traindata.csv',skip=4,head=F)[1:100,1:26]
X<-apply(cd[,,with=F],2,function(cc) as.numeric(sub(",", "", cc, fixed = TRUE)))
```

my understanding for the second one is that the author aims to replace separator "," with "". My question is that, when we read the csv file using fread, the separator "," in the original csv file should not be kept. Why we still need the second line of code to replace ",".

Comment: `csv` separator could be `;`. In this case `,` will still be there. As written in help : the separator between columns defaults to the character in the set [,\t |;:] that separates the sample of rows into the most number of lines with the same number of fields.

Comment: I bet that it has nothing to do with the field-separator in the CSV (since those are not see by the code outside of `fread`). The `as.numeric` suggests that the removal is of thousands-separators (e.g., `12,345.67` --> `12345.67`).